# Windows 10 DNS Issue

Tags: windows, networking, dns, windows-10

All of the sudden today Windows 10 stopped resolving names. When I try to do nslookup I always get this message:

```
S:\Users\dzoni>nslookup google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.4.4

*** UnKnown can't find google.com: No response from server
```

But what is strange is that only Chrome is working perfectly, it has no issues in resolving names and browsing works as expected. Everything else is unable to resolve. There is no IPv6 setup so that shouldn't cause issues. I have a local DNS server and all other PCs are working fine.

I've tried different DNS servers, disabled the Firewall, flushed the DNS cache, reset the NIC and still nothing.

Comment: Do you have multiple network adapters? Are you sure chrome can resolve anything else than google.com (it has that built-in)

Comment: Yes I have a wireless adapter as well but it's disabled. I tried using it and I have the same issues as on the Ethernet adapter. I am using Chrome to post here.

Comment: Is the DNS Client Windows Service running?

Comment: @CharlesH Yes the DNS Service is running, I tried restarting it but to no avail. I am starting to suspect that the PC is infected with something. It's acting very strange, unable to start specific administrative tools, this DNS issue. However Avast and Malwarebytes reported the PC is clean.

Comment: It is very strange, have you tried running a SFC /Scannow from administrative command prompt?

Comment: What do you mean 'There is no IPv6 setup so that shouldn't cause issues'? Windows 10 definitely has an IPv6 setup by default and that could be related to your problem.

Comment: @CharlesH I performed a scan and the results were bad. So I decided on a clean install.

Comment: @DainelK IPv6 disabled in the int config.

Answer (score 0):

On @CharlesH's suggestion I performed a system scan and found out that the system was infected with some malware that messed up all the services. Only solution is to perform a clean install.

All I can say, people be very very careful what you install on your computers.

Comment: Glad I could help!